# Creating areas within TFS through command line

Tags: tfs

When we're creating a new TFS project, we're looking to take areas from one or more existing projects and copy them to the new project. We'd also like to sync up the project areas (so if a user adds an area in one of the component projects, that gets propagated overnight to the release projects).

I don't want to go through the TFS UI, as snazzy as it is.

Is there an easy way to do this? I know I can play with the TFS API and the ICommonStructureService object to do this, but I was hoping for a batch file along the line of one of the "TF" or "TFPT" commands.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No answers. I decided to bite the bullet and go through the TFS API.

Comment: Sorry about that -- I'm no longer on that project and don't have access to the source code. From what I recall, I used the AreaRootNode property on the Project class. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.workitemtracking.client.project 

This link may also help:
http://geekswithblogs.net/TarunArora/archive/2011/07/10/tfs-2010-sdk-get-projects-iterations-area-path-queries-and.aspx